# Referencing subequations with cleveref

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, amsmath, cleveref

I try to refer to the parent number of subequations with `\cref` from the `cleveref` package. However, I would like to change the output "eq. (...)" into "eqs. (...)" when I refer to parent numbers instead of individual equation numbers. Unfortunately, this does not seem to be implemented by default, or at least there is no `\crefformat{parentequation}` or `\crefformat{subequation}` available.

A short example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{equation}{#2eq.~(#1)#3}
\Crefformat{equation}{#2Eq.~(#1)#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations} \label{parenteq}
\begin{align}
  x + y = z \label{subeq1} \\
  a + b = c \label{subeq2} 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\Cref{parenteq} consist of \cref{subeq1} and \cref{subeq2}.

\end{document}
```

I would like to see the output

> Eqs. (1) consist of eq. (1a) and eq. (1b).

instead of

> Eq. (1) consist of eq. (1a) and eq. (1b).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 12):

As a workaround you may define a plural equation label:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{pluralequation}{eqs.}{eqs.}
\Crefname{pluralequation}{Eqs.}{Eqs.}

\crefformat{equation}{#2eq.~(#1)#3}
\Crefformat{equation}{#2Eq.~(#1)#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations} \label{parenteq}\label[pluralequation]{parenteqs}
\begin{align}
  x + y = z \label{subeq1} \\
  a + b = c \label{subeq2} 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\Cref{parenteqs} consist of \cref{subeq1} and \cref{subeq2}.

\end{document}
```

If `\crefname` is not enough, you may use `\crefformat` and `\Crefformat` to define a `pluralequation` format in the same kind you've done with `equation`, e.g.;

```
\crefformat{pluralequation}{#2eqs.~(#1)#3}
\Crefformat{pluralequation}{#2Eqs.~(#1)#3}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to include the parenthesis '( )' into the output? `\crefname` does not seem to accept arguments like `\crefformat` does.

Comment: @Patrick G.: You may use `\crefformat` to define a format of `pluralequation`, e.g. `\Crefformat{pluralequation}{#2Eqs. (#1)#3}`. See my change above.

Comment: This works. Do you use the label `\label{parenteq}` twice on purpose? I think I dont understand how your workaround is supposed to function.

Comment: @Patrick G.: If used two different labels `parenteq` and `parenteqs`. So you can still reference the singular with `\cref{parenteq}`. BTW: Using a plural format has been described at the `cleveref` manual even.

Comment: Oh well, it seems to work anyway!