# Cleveref's \crefrange and mixed equations and subequations

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, cleveref

This example doesn't work with the latest version of `cleveref`.

The line
Refer to `\crefrange{eqa}{eqc}`.
gives the output:

```
Refer to ?? 1–3.
```

It used to work before.

Can anyone explain how to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\label{eqa}
\begin{align}
a &= b\\
c &= d
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations}
\label{eqba}
\begin{align}
e &= f\\
g &= h
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{equation}
\label{eqc}
i = j
\end{equation}

Refer to \crefrange{eqa}{eqc}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get it right. Did you compile at least twice?

Comment: Yes I ran it twice but keep getting the LaTeX Warning: References `eqa' and `eqc' in reference range on page 1 have different types `subequation' and `equation' on input line 28.

Comment: Some thing else is going on. With your code above I get `Refer to eqs. (1) to (3).`

Comment: Im running Miktex 2.9. What are you running?

Comment: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.6.30)  15 JAN 2014 07:42`

Comment: Weird, same version here.

Comment: I can confirm the bad behavior; in version 0.19 a modification to the management of `subequations` has been done, which apparently broke the functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Answer based on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35772/referencing-subequations-with-cleveref) and @egreg's comment that the `subequations` environment management has changed.)

You can force the top-level label of the `subequations` environment to be treated as an `equations`-environment label through an optional argument to `\label`:

```
\begin{subequations}
\label[equation]{eqlabel}
[...]
\end{subequations}
```

Your MWE would look like this (extra sub-equation labels added to show this does not affect the top-level label behaviour):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\label[equation]{eqa}
\begin{align}
\label{subeqa1}
a &= b \\
\label{subeqa2}
c &= d
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations}
\label[equation]{eqb}
\begin{align}
\label{subeqb1}
e &= f \\
\label{subeqb2}
g &= h
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{equation}
\label{eqc}
i = j
\end{equation}

Refer to \crefrange{eqa}{eqc}.

\end{document}
```

#### EDIT: The downside

It appears that labels declared as `\label[equation]{...}` are overlooked by RefTeX. This makes it a little less convenient to add references to top-level labels of a set of sub-equations if one is used to using RefTeX. I imagine there should be a simple way to fix this, but I do not know how.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with version 0.19 of cleveref (see the above comment by egreg). I fixed this behaviour by

```
\crefalias{subequation}{equation}
```

in the preamble.

(Please drop a comment if this fix is somehow dirty or should be avoided)